# Help with a difficult trigonometric integral

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

let $s$ be a complex parameter. We have the integral :

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\tan(sx)}{\tanh(s\log[\sec(x)])} \right ]\frac{\sec^{2}(x)}{e^{2\pi \tan(x)}-1}dx$$

This is a 'simplified' version of the rather unsettling integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\left[ \frac{ \tan\left( s\tan^{-1}(x)\right )}{\tanh\left(s\log\left(\sqrt{1+x^{2}} \right )\right)}\right ]\frac{dx}{e^{2\pi x}-1}$$

Any insight on how to do the integral is highly appreciated

---

EDIT1:

I am especially interested in the integral on the imaginary axis ($s=it,  \Im(t)=0)$

EDIT2

It turns out that i have made an innocent mistake. The integral doesn't converge, and has to be modified :
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\tan(sx)}{\tanh(s\log[\sec(x)])} \right ]-\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{x}{\log\sec(x)} \right ]\right)\frac{\sec^{2}(x)}{e^{2\pi \tan(x)}-1}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\tan^{-1}\left[ \frac{ \tan\left( s\tan^{-1}(x)\right )}{\tanh\left(s\log\left(\sqrt{1+x^{2}} \right )\right)}\right ]-\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{2\tan^{-1}(x)}{\log(1+x^{2}))} \right ]\right)\frac{dx}{e^{2\pi x}-1}$$

Comment: Appearance is not that inviting, but I would try to simplify $\tanh(s \log(\cdot))$ at first. set $\tan(x)=u$ then read $\arctan$ as the imaginary part of a logarithm. With a bit of luck and Frullani's theorem/differentiation under the integral sign, we may compute it.

Comment: A bit of context wouldn't hurt, anyway: where this integral comes from? It looks like some kind of topological degree with a twist.

Comment: actually it originated from a number-theoretic problem. but can you elaborate on the 'topological degree' remark .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_degree_theory $$2\pi i\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz $$ counts the zeroes of $f$ inside $C$. If you are trying to compute the numbers of zeroes of the Riemann $\zeta$ function inside some contour in the critical strip, please write your complete derivation, it will be easier for everyone.

Comment: No actually. it has to do with this problem [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123571/analytic-continuation-of-the-dirichlet-generating-series-of-the-multiplicative-p) . where i succeeded to replace the Euler-Maclaurin summation with an Abel-plana formula. The integral above is just a 'nicer' way to write $$-\frac{i}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\log\left[\frac{\sinh\left(s\log(1+ix) \right )}{\sinh\left(s\log(1-ix) \right )} \right ]\frac{dx}{e^{2\pi x}-1}$$

Comment: It seems no friendly enough. It's hard to believe there is a closed expression for it.

Comment: well, i can give it a closed form. and in a rather extended domain of convergence, i can calculate it to an exquisite accuracy. the problem is with simplifications, and symmetries. and to be specific, i'll be more than happy if i can compute the above integral for $s=it$.

Comment: You may use the Weierstrass product for the $\sinh$ (or $\sin$) function and the problem boils down to computing $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\log\left(1+\frac{s^2\log^2(1+ix)}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yes indeed. I have considered this thought, thoroughly, no luck, alas ! this integral isn't any nicer .